Error AADSTS50049: "Unknown or invalid instance" in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC with Azure AD B2C
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application and using Azure AD B2C for authentication management. Below is my appsettings.json configuration:
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://test555.b2clogin.com",
  "ClientId": "test555",
  "Domain": "test555.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn"
}

Here is how I have configured my Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { Configuration["ProsperityPilot:ProsperityPilotScope"] })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
}

Up to this point, everything works fine. I can log in, sign up/sign out using Azure AD B2C, and make API calls obtaining the token like this:
private async Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
{
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _todoListScope });
    Debug.WriteLine($"access token-{accessToken}");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

However, I wanted to use IClaimsTransformation to add some claims when a user logs in. I wrote the following method to get a token, but I get the error:

AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance.

 public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
 {
     
    ///...

     var token = await GetApplicationTokenAsync();

     // search Users by email
     var userEmail = principal.Identity.Name;
     var user = await _service.GetByEmailAsync(userEmail, token);

     ///...

     return clone;
 }

Here is my GetApplicationTokenAsync:
private async Task<string> GetApplicationTokenAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var clientId = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"]; // ClientId of the WebApp
        var clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"]; // ClientId of the WebApp
        var scope = _configuration["MyApp:MyAppScope"]; // exposed API scope access_as_user
        var tenant = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"];
        var policy = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];

        var tenantName = "mytenant";
        var authority = $"https://{tenantName}.b2clogin.com/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/v2.0";


        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { scope }).ExecuteAsync();
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Questions:

What is the correct way to configure the authority to obtain a token in an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application using Azure AD B2C?
Do I need to configure a separate DownstreamApi? If so, how should I correctly set it up?


REPO:
I have created this repository to facilitate clear visibility and analysis of the issue I am encountering, allowing for a deeper understanding of the error.

Azure ApiApp Config:

API permissions
Expose an API
I have 1 Certificate & secret
Authentication


Azure WebApp Config:

Authentication
I have 1 Certificate & secret
API permissions
In the Expose an API section I have nothing


Have you tried removing the /v2.0 from the authority? MSAL might add that.

Yes, I have tried

Your configuration has
{
  "Domain": "test555.onmicrosoft.com"
}

and then it is used:
var tenant = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"];
var authority = $"https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/v2.0";

This means authority ends up being an invalid value:
https://test555.onmicrosoft.com.b2clogin.com/test555.onmicrosoft.com.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn/v2.0

Notice how the domain has duplicate text in it?
You need a config value with just "test555", then it should work.

I'm getting the same error. At this point my question is The clientId, clientSecret are from my MVC application, the scope is from my API application, is this correct?

Yeah, that should be correct.

I added my Azure AD configurations. And I tried your suggestions about var authority but I'm always getting the same error.
